# Can we over sensitise people

Tags: neuroscience, anxiety, therapy

Is there evidence that "over sensitivising" an indvidual (eg adolescent) makes them less resilient? So to explain, if we ask an individual repeatedly how they feel and if they have been mistreated, they might eventually feel more depressed or mistreated.

For example there might be a neurological reason by activating certain "fear centres" (amygdala) of the brain.

Could we be robbing people of self coping strategies, if we repeatedly analyse the issues for them?

Please don't misinterpret this question in a political sense, I really mean from a psychological POV.